# Using JQ to filter JSON data at different levels

Tags: json, jq, text-manipulation

I have this JSON data : **some-json-file** which contains the following

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "1234567812345678",
      "name": "somewebsite.com",
      "status": "active",
      "type": "secondary",
      "activated_on": "2021-12-12T15:44:40.444433Z",
      "plan": {
        "id": "77777777777777777777777777",
        "name": "Enterprise Website",
        "is_subscribed": true,
        "legacy_id": "enterprise",
        "externally_managed": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "result_info": {
    "page": 1,
    "total_pages": 1
  },
  "success": true,
  "messages": []
}
```

And I am trying to get this filtered output from it using **jq**

```
{
  "name": "somewebsite.com",
  "type": "secondary",
  "plan": {
    "name": "Enterprise Website",
    "id": "77777777777777777777777777"
  }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do that.

I can filter the first layer of labels like this

```
cat some-json-file | jq '.result[] | {name,type,plan}'
```

Which gets me this output

```
{
  "name": "somewebsite.com",
  "type": "secondary",
  "plan": {
    "id": "77777777777777777777777777",
    "name": "Enterprise Website",
    "is_subscribed": true,
    "legacy_id": "enterprise",
    "externally_managed": true
  }
}
```

That gets me close, but I can't further filter the child labels under **.plan** so that I see just the **.name** and **.id**.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Just set the new context and use the same technique again:

```sh
jq '.result[] | {name,type,plan: .plan | {name,id}}' some-json-file
```

```json
{
  "name": "somewebsite.com",
  "type": "secondary",
  "plan": {
    "name": "Enterprise Website",
    "id": "77777777777777777777777777"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bIePUljlxc)

Note: You don't need to `cat` the input, `jq` accepts the filename as parameter.

Comment: Beautiful easy solution! Thank you! How did you figure this out? Is there a resource explaining this syntax?

Comment: The [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) has all the examples. (See especially sections [Pipe](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Pipe:|) and [Object Construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D))